# GetFromJsonAsync by custom Id

Tags: c#, json, api, razor, blazor

I'm using Blazor WebAssembly and I want to do a GetFromJsonAsync from a URI based on the ID entered by the client.
Practically, the client will enter an ID in the label, and depending on it, he will receive a list. That URI is formed according to the entered ID.

```
@page "/dentistappointments"
@using WhiteDentalClinic.Application.Models.AppointmentModel;
@using WhiteDentalClinic.Application.Models;
@inject HttpClient Http

`<h3>DentistAppointments</h3>

<EditForm class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <InputText @bind-Value="@dentistId"/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">See appointments:</button>
</EditForm>

@if (appByDentist == null)
{
    <p><em>No dentist appointments found.</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Date time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var app in appByDentist)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@app.Id</td>
                    <td>@app.dateTime</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
@code {
    private List<AppointmentResponse> appByDentist = new List<AppointmentResponse>();

    private var dentistId = "87459b92-79d6-44b3-850e-727d90519ba3";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var temp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<IEnumerable<AppointmentResponse>>>($"/api/Appointment/allapp/dentist{dentistRequestId}", dentistId);
        appByDentist = temp.Result.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add how the http client is set up and how looks endpoint being called.

Comment: But my guess would be that you have mailformed url - after quick peek I could not find overload of `GetFromJsonAsync` accepting 2 parameters. Try forming url like `$"/api/Appointment/allapp/dentist/{dentistRequestId}"` or `$"/api/Appointment/allapp/dentist?dentistRequestId={dentistRequestId}"`. Possibly prefix with server address.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to connect from API to frontend (blazor) with Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<IEnumerable<AppointmentResponse>>>($"/api/Appointment/allapp/dentist{dentistRequestId}"}.   My problem is how can i do this dynamic URL? I can't do a private a private var or string dentistRequestId because i would have an JsonSerialize error

Answer (score -1):

Try this :
private List appByDentist = new List();

```
private var dentistId = "87459b92-79d6-44b3-850e-727d90519ba3";

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var url = $"/api/Appointment/allapp/dentist/{dentistId}"
    var temp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<IEnumerable<AppointmentResponse>>>(url, dentistId);
    appByDentist = temp.Result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why should OP try this? How does this differ from OP's code? We don't even know, what OP's issue is ...